Android app that is controlled via bluetooth remote
I have a remote control for a selfie stick. Is it possible to write an android app in which I can redefine the button presses to my own. At the same time, disable the standard behavior (swipes up/down) of the remote?
I also tried to connect the Xiaomi TV remote to the application. But I could not subscribe to button presses.

By Bluetooth I assume you mean BLE. In BLE devices communicate through characteristics, so for receiving key presses you have to pair the bLE device and register for notifications on the correct characteristics. Not sure if this is standardized or a custom characteristics is used. That is something you have to investigate. You can check characteristics e.g, using an app like "nrf connect".
